# Trouble with Arrays in vba

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Thank you for all of the help. I have successfully populated and reviewed the contents of my array. Now I am having trouble calling the specific instances (string values) within the array in a function I wrote to compare cells in the sheet to the values in the array....

I am getting the "subscript out of range" inside of my function in my strcomp(). I have checked and the right value is being passed via vCompare.

Arrays are so finicky!

Here is the updated code:

```
Sub searchTrucks()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim EndRow As Long
Dim showAll As Boolean
Dim BeginRow As Long
Dim RowCnt As Long
Dim chckTech As Long
Dim chckReg As Long
Dim chckSite As Long
Dim chckUnum As Long
Dim chckType As Long
Dim chckAge As Long
Dim chckDt As Long
Dim chckCap As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim aRan As Range
Dim bRan As Range
Dim cRan As Range
Dim rrRan As Range
Dim rmRan As Range
Dim marray() As Variant
marray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Worksheets("Calculations").Range("F2:K2"))
Dim vCompare As String
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
y = 2
x = 1
i = 1
lastRow = Application.CountA(Sheets("Trucks").Range("C:C"))
BeginRow = 6
EndRow = lastRow + 4
chckSite = 3
chckUnum = 4
chckType = 5
chckAge = 7
chckDt = 10
chckCap = 11
Debug.Print lastRow
For i = 1 To 8
    If IsEmpty(Sheets("Trucks").Cells(2, i).Value) Then
        showAll = True
    Else
        showAll = False
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
Debug.Print showAll
If showAll = False Then
For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
        If Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Trucks").Cells(2, 3).Value) And IsEmpty(Sheets("Trucks").Cells(2, 4).Value) Then
            For y = 2 To 6
            If Sheets("Trucks").Cells(2, 3).Value = Sheets("Calculations").Cells(y, 5).Value Then
                    vCompare = Sheets("Trucks").Cells(RowCnt, chckSite).Value
                    If IsInArray(vCompare, marray) = -1 Then
                        Cells(RowCnt, chckSite).EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    End If
            End If
            Next
Stop
        End If
        If Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Trucks").Cells(2, 4).Value) And Sheets("Trucks").Cells(RowCnt, chckSite).Value <> Sheets("Trucks").Cells(2, 4).Value Then
            Cells(RowCnt, chckSite).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Trucks").Cells(2, 5).Value) And Sheets("Trucks").Cells(RowCnt, chckUnum).Value <> Sheets("Trucks").Cells(2, 5).Value Then
            Cells(RowCnt, chckUnum).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Trucks").Cells(2, 6).Value) And Sheets("Trucks").Cells(RowCnt, chckType).Value <> Sheets("Trucks").Cells(2, 6).Value Then
            Cells(RowCnt, chckType).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Trucks").Cells(2, 7).Value) And Sheets("Trucks").Cells(RowCnt, chckAge).Value < Sheets("Trucks").Cells(2, 7).Value Then
            Cells(RowCnt, chckAge).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Trucks").Cells(2, 9).Value) And Sheets("Trucks").Cells(RowCnt, chckDt).Value < Sheets("Trucks").Cells(2, 9).Value Then
            Cells(RowCnt, chckDt).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Trucks").Cells(2, 10).Value) And Sheets("Trucks").Cells(RowCnt, chckCap).Value < Sheets("Trucks").Cells(2, 10).Value Then
            Cells(RowCnt, chckCap).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next RowCnt
Else
    Sheets("Trucks").Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
```

Here is my function code:

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Long
  Dim i As Long
  ' default return value if value not found in array
  IsInArray = -1
Debug.Print stringToBeFound

  For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If StrComp(stringToBeFound, arr(i), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
      IsInArray = i
      Exit For
    End If
  Next i
End Function
```

Comment: You use the `Array` function in VBA like this `Array(1,2,3,5)` or `Array("a","b","c")`. What sort of data is in the "Calculations" sheet in range "F2:K2" - and can you paste an example (like a picture) of that sheet. You are not using arrays correctly - but in order to tell you how to use correctly, need bit more info.

Comment: using `aArray = worksheetfunction.transpose(Sheets("Calculations").Range("F2:K2"))` should populate your arrays correctly

Comment: similarly, there are numerous examples on SO of how to search an array for a particular value that don't require multiple `if...else` statements.

Comment: and you don't need `step 1` in your `for` loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To populate your arrays you can do this

```
Dim aArray As Variant

aArray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Worksheets("Calculations").Range("F2:K2"))
```

And similarly for all the rest of your arrays.

You cannot use `debug.print` on arrays. Instead, in your VBA editor right-click on the variable name (`aArray`) and select "Add watch". Your variable will appear in the "Watches" window. Now add a break-point just after you (correctly) populate `aArray` in the code and run your code. It will stop at the break-point and you can now go into the "Watches" window and expand the `aArray` variable. You will see the contents of the array here.

Regarding the use of the `Array` function, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262675(v=vs.60).aspx) -  a comma delimited list of items is required. It is often used to do quick-and-dirty creation of variant arrays, often for static data consisting of small lists. For instance, things like `Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar",...,"Dec")`... stuff like that.

You generally do not need to call this constructor explicitly when using arrays. For simple non-Variant data types an array of type X is defined like so:

```
dim an_X_array(10) as X
```

This defines `an_X_array` to be an array of 10 items that each have type `X`

Compare this to a simple variable defined to be of type `X`

```
dim an_X as X
```

With regards to your second problem - it is being caused by the array you create from your range (worksheet data) being constructed as a 2-dimensional array. You can either work with 2-dimensional arrays, and change your formulas, or use the below helper function to create a 1-dimensional array from your worksheet data. Here is the function to create a proper 1-dimensional array from any worksheet range (just copy-paste it somewhere in your code module):

```
Public Function RngToArray(ByRef InputRange As Range) As Variant

Dim A As Variant
Dim rr As Range
Dim i As Long

ReDim A(InputRange.Cells.Count)
i = LBound(A)

For Each rr In InputRange
    A(i) = rr.Value
    i = i + 1
Next

ReDim Preserve A(i - 1)
RngToArray = A

End Function
```

And for your example you then need to replace just one line of your code:

change

```
marray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Worksheets("Calculations").Range("F2:K2"))
```

to

```
marray = RngToArray(Worksheets("Calculations").Range("F2:K2"))
```

Comment: Rusan -Thank you so much for the help. I have successfully populated and confirmed my array's contents. In the "watch" window, my array shows aArray(1)... aArray(2) etc all the way to the last value. There is a plus sign next to each expression that allows me to see the values. The only issue is the values are shown under aArray(1,1). Now, when I try to pass my array into a function to be checked for string it is "supscript out of range"

Comment: Function code: `Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Long
  Dim i As Long
  ' default return value if value not found in array
  IsInArray = -1
Debug.Print stringToBeFound

  For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If StrComp(stringToBeFound, arr(i), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
      IsInArray = i
      Exit For
    End If
  Next i
End Function`

Comment: sub code: `If Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Trucks").Cells(2, 3).Value) And IsEmpty(Sheets("Trucks").Cells(2, 4).Value) Then
            For y = 2 To 6
            If Sheets("Trucks").Cells(2, 3).Value = Sheets("Calculations").Cells(y, 5).Value Then
                    vCompare = Sheets("Trucks").Cells(RowCnt, chckSite).Value
                    If IsInArray(vCompare, marray) = -1 Then
                        Cells(RowCnt, chckSite).EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    End If
            End If
            Next`

Comment: `Dim marray() As Variant
marray = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Worksheets("Calculations").Range("F2:K2"))
Dim vCompare As String`

Comment: @Zane where exactly (what line) are you getting an error? You can step through code line-by-line by using the F8 key (it will highlight lines to be executed in yellow, by default). I have checked the function "IsInArray" and it works fine for me.

Comment: I have edited my original question to reflect my progress. I have also reduced my code quite a bit to help me keep track of the logic. The error happens inside of my function at this line: `If StrComp(stringToBeFound, arr(i), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then`

Comment: @Zane OK..so add a watch to each of those things (`stringToBeFound`, `arr`, `vbTextCompare`). Put a breakpoint on that line and execute to that line (it should highlight in yellow). Then you can read off what the exact values are before the line is executed. Can you report them back here?

Comment: As requested:   arr(1,1) = "Bloomsburg" and is type Variant/String. arr holds 6 values, all of which are correctly populated just like the above mentioned and are of the same type. stringToBeFound = "Whitehall" which is the correct string value passed to the function. vbTextCompare = 1. Not sure why, the strings dont match, but thus we have an issue with the array.

Comment: I should note that the stringtobefound value does not match any of the strings in the array.

Comment: OK - sorry for delays - different time-zones. I guess. The issues *seems* to be you have a two-dimensional array `arr`. The reason you have a two-dimensional array is because your data (range) is split over columns. `arr` is constructed as a 1-dimensional array if your data is split over rows (i.e. all in one column). There is no easy way around this - the quickest thing for you would be to use the helper function I have edited my answer with. The function is called `RngToArray` and it makes an array from a range that you give it.

Comment: Or, correct me if I'm wrong, I can simply change the range pushed into the array from row Cx:Jx to colunm Cx:Cy.... that will take a matter of minutes. I will give it a try. How did you figure that out?

Comment: Also, no worries on the delay, this is a personal project that has no deadline

Comment: I just played around with it in VBA - yes, I tested it out on `Range("A1:A3")` i.e. all in one column - and it returns a 1-dimensional array. But when I saw you keep referring to `arr(1,1)` (i.e. two dimensional) I wondered it data split over cols might be causing it. And your function worked fine..so just a process of elimination. Might be easier to just use my helper function..rather than mess around with data on your worksheet....

Comment: everything runs like a dream. thanks again for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

the way you populate your array , you will get a 2 dimensional array, so i modified your source code to test if your value is in the array :

```
Function IsInArray( Byval stringToBeFound As String, Byref arr As Variant) As Long
  Dim i As Long 'i is the columns variable
  Dim J& 'j is the rows variable
  ' default return value if value not found in array
  IsInArray = -1
  Debug.Print stringToBeFound

  For i = LBound(arr,2) To UBound(arr,2) 'the ,2 is to say the 2nd dimension (same order of dimensions as if you'd use the cells function)
      For j = LBound(arr,1) To UBound(arr,1)
          If stringToBeFound = arr(j,i) Then 'simple test of strings
              IsInArray = i 'will give the column as answer
              Exit Function 'Exit For
          End If
      Next i
End Function
```